# How do I disable the sign up link for the aws amplify vue authenticator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-vue

I'm using the `amplify-authenticator` component from the `aws-amplify-vue` library to enable authentication for my app. I'm trying to figure out how to disable the "Create Account" link on the front end and I can't seem to find anything in the documentation or online.  I've seen a few places where users disabled it by hiding it with css and a few places where users were able to disable it with the react library, but I haven't found anything specific for the vue library. It's possible I'm just missing the documentation, but does anyone know how to remove the sign up functionality from the vue amplify authenticator?

## Component

[image]

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <amplify-authenticator></amplify-authenticator>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import logger from "../logging";
import { components } from "aws-amplify-vue";
import { AmplifyEventBus } from "aws-amplify-vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    ...components
  }
})
export default class Login extends Vue {
  async created() {
    try {
      // This function throws an error if no user is logged in
      await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true });
      this.$router.push("/instruments");
    } catch (e) {
      logger.silly("No user currently logged in");

      AmplifyEventBus.$on("authState", async info => {
        logger.silly("signedIn");
        logger.silly(info);
        if (info === "signedIn") {
          const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
            bypassCache: true
          });
          this.$router.push("/instruments");
        } else {
          logger.error(`Failed to login`);
          alert("Failed to login");
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

## Update 1

Based on @asimpledevice's answer I tried the below without success:

```
<template>
  <v-container class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
    <amplify-authenticator
      :authConfig="authConfiguration"
    ></amplify-authenticator>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import StoreTypes from "../store-types";
import logger from "../logging";
import { components } from "aws-amplify-vue";
import { AmplifyEventBus } from "aws-amplify-vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    ...components
  }
})
export default class Login extends Vue {
  async mounted() {
    try {
      // This function throws an error if no user is logged in
      await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true });
      this.$router.push("/instruments");
    } catch (e) {
      const self = this;
      AmplifyEventBus.$on("authState", async info => {
        if (info === "signedIn") {
          this.$store.dispatch(StoreTypes.types.LOAD_CURRENT_USER);
          const nextLocation =
            self.$route.query.redirect !== null &&
            self.$route.query.redirect !== undefined
              ? (self.$route.query.redirect as string)
              : "/instruments";
          this.$router.push(nextLocation).catch(err => {});
        }
      });
    }
  }

  authConfiguration() {
    return {
      signInConfig: {
        isSignUpDisplayed: false
      }
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can hide the "sign up" section via the "signInConfig" object.

```
  configurationOptions: any = {
    signInConfig: {
      isSignUpDisplayed: false
    }
  };
```

You can then pass this object in as a prop to the  component:

```
    <amplify-authenticator
      :authConfig="configurationOptions"
    ></amplify-authenticator>
```

***NOTE:*** You must make the config object a local property.  The config will not work if it is a function or computed property. Your full solution would be the following:

```
<template>
  <v-container class="d-flex justify-center align-center">
    <amplify-authenticator
      :authConfig="configurationOptions"
    ></amplify-authenticator>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import StoreTypes from "../store-types";
import logger from "../logging";
import { components } from "aws-amplify-vue";
import { AmplifyEventBus } from "aws-amplify-vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    ...components
  }
})
export default class Login extends Vue {
  configurationOptions: any = {
    signInConfig: {
      isSignUpDisplayed: false
    }
  };

  async mounted() {
    try {
      // This function throws an error if no user is logged in
      await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true });
      this.$router.push("/instruments");
    } catch (e) {
      const self = this;
      AmplifyEventBus.$on("authState", async info => {
        if (info === "signedIn") {
          this.$store.dispatch(StoreTypes.types.LOAD_CURRENT_USER);
          const nextLocation =
            self.$route.query.redirect !== null &&
            self.$route.query.redirect !== undefined
              ? (self.$route.query.redirect as string)
              : "/instruments";
          this.$router.push(nextLocation).catch(err => {});
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: I tried this approach in my code (see updated answer), but I was unsuccessful.  Any additional thoughts? (p.s. Welcome to SO!)

Comment: thanks for the welcome!

it doesn't seem to like it when it's passed in as a function rather than as a property. could you try changing it from:

  authConfiguration() {
    return {
      signInConfig: {
        isSignUpDisplayed: false
      }
    };
  }

to just a local property?

  authConfiguration: any = {
    signInConfig: {
      isSignUpDisplayed: false
    }
  };

Comment: How can I do this in React?

Answer (score 7):

With `@aws-amplify/auth ^3.2.6` and `@aws-amplify/ui-vue ^0.2.20` this works as documented in [Sign In docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/vue#sign-in)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <amplify-authenticator username-alias="email">
      <amplify-sign-in slot="sign-in" :hide-sign-up="true"
        username-alias="email">
      </amplify-sign-in>
    </amplify-authenticator>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work with a simplified inline expression:

```
<amplify-authenticator :authConfig="{ signInConfig: { isSignUpDisplayed: false } }" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this, in Angular 8 it works.

```
<amplify-authenticator>
  <amplify-sign-in slot="sign-in" hide-sign-up="true"></amplify-sign-in>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **withAuthenticator**:

```
const withAuthenticatorOptions = {
  hideSignUp: true
}

export default withAuthenticator(MyApp, withAuthenticatorOptions);
```

[AWS doc](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/configuration#hide-sign-up)

Comment: Always try to write your code in code block. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If using the [`Amplify UI for Vue`](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/vue/connected-components/authenticator/configuration#hide-sign-up), then this is as easy as binding `:hide-sign-up="true"` in the authenticator:

```
<template>
  <authenticator :hide-sign-up="true">
    <template v-slot="{ user, signOut }">
      <h1>Hello {{ user.username }}!</h1>
      <button @click="signOut">Sign Out</button>
    </template>
  </authenticator>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried on Quasar and this option worked for me.