# How do I disable the sign up link for the aws amplify vue authenticator, for the new API?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, aws-amplify

The new `"@aws-amplify/ui-vue"` API works differently from the old `"aws-amplify-vue"`.  So the answer to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045960/how-do-i-disable-the-sign-up-link-for-the-aws-amplify-vue-authenticator) don't work any more.

Is there a way, using the new API, to disable the "Create Account" link on the front end?

Thanks!